# Get user ID from Email Firebase (not current user)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have an email and I need to get the ID of this account. I use the email/password login method and I have a collection with complementary user information. What can I do to do this ?

Comment: First of all, where are account IDs stored?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you could do:

-When a user signs up, save their related user information under their designated User ID in a collection called 'users'.

-Then you could use a query to find the user with the specified email address.

-Query could be something like:

```
db.collection("users").whereField("email", isEqualTo: emailYouHave)
.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            // This is where you would get the ID, there should only be one document
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea but I tried this but I need to do this on 1 to 200 emails so I need to use a func that return the ID.

Comment: @ChristopheRoulin This is a pretty solid answer and it directly answers your question about getting the user ID from an email. Can you clarify what *I need to do this on 1 to 200 emails* means as the initial question is asking about one.

Comment: Okay so you could just wrap the above code in a function with a 'email' parameter.